# QGIS - Cartesian Join

Tags: qgis, query

Is it possible to run a cartesian join in QGIS?  I use Access to do this but I would like to know if I can do it directly in QGIS (or GRASS GIS) to avoid the back and forth between the GIS and Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u can achieve such a join using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers** you can then try queries like the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
```

Care about the size of the tables you use in the query ...

Comment: Thanks, How do you create a join if there are some common points in the tables?

Comment: I think the above query should would work ... you should just have a **unique field id** to discriminate them ... or do you mean duplicates ?

Comment: i am familiar with Access, but I should be able to do the same from GIS. If there isa common ID between two tables, then I should be able to run a query.